# create an anonymous class pass in the constructor arguments and implement its interface

Tags: java

```
java version "1.7.0_45"
```

Hello,

class with constructor arguments that has an interface that will be implemented in the client

```
public class SInvitationListenerImp {
    public interface MUCRoomListener {
        void onInvitationReceived(String roomName, String inviter, String reason, String password, String message);
    }

    public SInvitationListenerImp(MUCRoomListener roomListenerEvent, int clientConnection) {
        mMUCRoomListener = roomListenerEvent;
        mClientConnection = clientConnection;
    }
}
```

And in my client could I would like to create a anonymous class pass in the constructor arguments and implement the interface.

However, this doesn't work with the arguements

```
new SInvitationListenerImp(MainActivity.this, connection).MUCRoomListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInvitationReceived(String s, String s1, String s2, String s3, String s4) {

            }
        };
```

This works without the constructor arguments. However, the arguments are needed (So this woudn't work for my needs)

```
new SInvitationListenerImp.MUCRoomListener() {
      @Override
          public void onInvitationReceived(String s, String s1, String s2, String s3, String s4) {
      }
};
```

Is this possible to pass arguments to the constructor and implement the interface?

Many thanks for any suggestions

UPDATE results in `'.' or ')' expected`:

```
new SInvitationListenerImp(new SInvitationListenerImp.MUCRoomListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInvitationReceived(String s, String s1, String s2, String s3, String s4) {
        }
    } MainActivity.this, connection);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong... You probably need something like this,

```
new SInvitationListenerImp(new SInvitationListenerImp.MUCRoomListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInvitationReceived(String s, String s1, String s2, String s3, String s4) {
                // Interface method body.
            }

        }, connection);
```

Comment: thanks but that didn't work. I get an error at the last } curly brace '.' or ')' expected. I have updated my question with your current solution.

Comment: @ant2009, I just saw your update... Why is `MainActivity.this` used there?

Comment: its the class object that gets passed to the library so that it can call back events through the interface. MainActivity.this is not a problem, as I have tested the same code with an int value. Thanks.

Comment: Your constructor doesn't accept any object like that... It only accepts 2 parameters, an `MUCRoomListener` and an `int`... You cannot pass anything else in it...